# Can we debug a running process in Visual Studio using PDB file and incomplete source code?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, debugging, visual-studio-debugging, pdb-files

I have to debug a running process for which I have matching PDB file, but do not have complete source code. Is it possible to debug specific functions in the available C++ source code?

I tried configuring PDB file and source code paths in VS and then attached to the running process, but execution is not stopping at expected locations.
I added debug points in the available source code but it is not making any change because the binaries are built using VS.

Comment: (1/2) What do you mean by "incomplete source code"? Does it mean that you have some of the cpp files but not all of them or something? I doubt that debugging with only parts of the source code is possible, as what makes it possible to debug from source in VS is the fact that VS knows which part of the compiled code corresponds to which part of the source code because it actually compiled it itself, which is not the case if you only have some of the files and a PDB. PDBs are mostly symbols and types, it does allow seeing function names and stuff, but certainly not debugging with incomplete code

Comment: (2/2) However, if you are willing to debug without your source code parts, you can still attach a debugger to your running process and debug from assembly. Some debuggers will let you import your PDB with that to have symbols along with the assembly. It sure will take more time to debug, though.

Comment: yes you can, just follow this official document: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/attach-to-running-processes-with-the-visual-studio-debugger?view=vs-2022

Comment: I posted an answer, you can take a look. :)

Comment: @RedStoneMatt , The source code can not be compiled using VS, I have matching binaries, source and PDBs. For debugging few functions I have required source files for those functions. Not all source code is available on the machine where VS is installed but I can copy some required source files.

Answer (score 0):

> Can we debug a running process in Visual Studio using PDB file and
> incomplete source code?

Yes, you can.

**But the extremely vital thing you need to pay attention is the source files used for debugging must be the same version as the ones used to build the binary and the PDB file must match the binary exactly.**

An official document that explain this:

[Why does Visual Studio require debugger symbol files to *exactly* match the binary files that they were built with?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/jimgries/why-does-visual-studio-require-debugger-symbol-files-to-exactly-match-the-binary-files-that-they-were-built-with)

For example, I created a MFC Cpp file on my side, the major structure of the solution/project is:

[image]

After I build the solution/project, a execution application will be generated under the solution directory:

[image]

You just need to pick up the execution application and related pdb like this(Make sure they are in the same directory. This step is to make sure when attach binary file .exe, the VS will be able to find the related pdb file.):

[image]

After that, follow this official document to use attach process feature to achieve your requirement:

[Attach to running processes with the Visual Studio debugger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/attach-to-running-processes-with-the-visual-studio-debugger?view=vs-2022)

At this time, even I remove all of other cpp files, I am still able to hit the breakpoint in View Tree:

[image]

Comment: In my case, the code can not be compiled using VS, however I can copy few source files required for debug few specific functions. I have matching source code / binaries / pdb files.